# MySQL - 'Permission denied' when trying to connect from webapp

Tags: php, mysql

when I am trying to connect database to my web application I get error 'Permission denied'. Which is quite wierd because I am using root (and password is correct).

I can connect manually from terminal without a problem.

Another wierd thing is when I try to connect using mysql -hHOST -uUSER -p and press `show databases;` it only show 2 of 6 databases (information schema and teampass where I want to connect the web app to.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| teampass           |
+--------------------+
```

when connecting from terminal using mysql -u root -p:

```
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| mysql               |
| db2                 |
| teampass            |
| db4                 |
| db3                 |
+---------------------+
```

any idea where could be a problem?

Comment: Probably you don't have remote access to these databases with that account. (Yes, even with root that's possible)

Comment: I found that so I tried GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; but nothing changed, any idea how to give him the remote access?

Comment: Did you also execute a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after that command?

Comment: Yes, Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: How many sql servers do you have on your machine

Comment: I have the same problem after moving the datadir and made a symbolic link on this directory. But only after restarting linux